# Django template dynamic load library

Tags: django

Is it possible to load different template libraries based on user permissions?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% if perms.app.my_permission %}
{% load lib1 %}
{% else %}
{% load lib2 %}
{% endif %}
<html>
<body>
    <h1>{% version %}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The template loader doesn't complain about the above, but my tags always reference those in lib2 rather than lib1.

For example:
app/templatetags/lib1.py

```
@register.simple_tag()
def version():
    return 'I am from lib1'
```

app/templatetags/lib2.py

```
@register.simple_tag()
def version():
    return 'I am from lib2'
```

And regardless of the user permission, I get

## I am from lib2

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% if perms.app.my_permission %}
  {% load lib1 %} 
  I will be here only for logged in users with the correct permission
{% else %}
  {% load lib2 %}
  I am for everyone else
{% endif %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#permissions

Comment: This doesn't work. As per my question, if I have a "version" template tag in both libraries, it uses the one from lib2 regardless of whether it should be called from lib1 or lib2

Comment: Its pretty much that in the question, but I'll provide a better example

Comment: How are you setting the model permissions? It should be something like 
class App(models.Model):
...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (("my_permission", "Can see lib1."),)

Comment: Its not a permissions thing as if I add the text that you proposed the correct text appears as I expect. Its something to do with {% load %} being executed regardless of the context...as in {% load ... %} is run regardless of where it is on the page